# toggle, close active one by clicking it

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have this toggle code but I would like to change it. I would like to add the possibility to close the active one by just clicking it. how can I do this?
so all the questions are shown, now if you click question it shows answer. if you click other question it closes the active on. But you cant click the active one to close.

The code :

```
    (function () {
            var $box = $('.acc-box');
            $box.each(function () {

                var $trigger = $('.acc-trigger', this);
                $trigger.first().addClass(':hidden').next().slideUp(300);

                $trigger.on('click', function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if ($this.data('mode') === 'toggle') {
                        $this.toggleClass('active').next().stop(true, true).slideToggle(300);
                    } else if ($this.next().is(':hidden')) {
                        $trigger.removeClass('active').next().slideUp(300);
                        $this.toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(300);
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }());
```

HTML

````
<div class="acc-box">

   <span data-mode='' class='acc-trigger'>
    <a href='#'>QUESTION</a>
   </span>
   <div class='acc-container'>
   <p>ANSWER</p>
   </div><!--/ .acc-container-->    

<span data-mode='' class='acc-trigger'>
    <a href='#'>QUESTION2</a>
   </span>
   <div class='acc-container'>
   <p>ANSWER2</p>
   </div><!--/ .acc-container-->    

<span data-mode='' class='acc-trigger'>
    <a href='#'>QUESTION3</a>
   </span>
   <div class='acc-container'>
   <p>ANSWER3</p>
   </div><!--/ .acc-container-->    

</div>```
````

Comment: Please share the rest of the html to have a clearer picture of what needs to happen. A jsfiddle/codesandbox would be good.

Comment: i added the html

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
(function () {
  var $box = $('.acc-box');
  $box.each(function () {

    var $trigger = $('.acc-trigger', this);
    $trigger.first().addClass(':hidden').next().slideUp(300);

    $trigger.on('click', function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
        if ($this.data('mode') === 'toggle') {
          $this.toggleClass('active').next().stop(true, true).slideToggle(300);
        } else if ($this.next().is(':hidden')) {
          $trigger.removeClass('active').next().slideUp(300);
          $this.toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(300);
        }
      }
      return false;
    });
  });
}());

$('a').on('click', function(){
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
     $('.acc-container').each(function() {
       $(this).hide();
     });
  }
});
```